# When...+present perfect

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, past-simple, perfect-constructions, past-vs-present-perfect

Is

> Susan does not live here,When I first came here three years ago, she **has** moved to another city.

Or

> Susan does not live here,When I first came here three years ago, she **had** moved to another city.

is better?
Also,can perfect tense use with "when"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either:  when I first came here three years ago she moved to another city, meaning that she moved when you arrived.

Or: when I first came here three years ago, she had moved to another city, meaning she was already gone when you arrived.

You cannot use "has moved" with "three years ago".